# How to set thousands seperators with two decimal places?

Tags: android, android-edittext, number-formatting

In my application ,am restricting the user to enter 7.2 digits(like 1234567.12).While entering it should be displayed as 1,234,567.12.But it has to be saved in database as 1234567.12.I am using decimal format as"###,###.##" to display in edit text box.But it is getting error on parsing with float ,while am saving in database.Please tell me any suggestions.

On Formatting ,am using this formatter _decimalFormat =new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.##");

```
        _decimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        _decimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
```

in ontextChanged listener,On saving in database i am getting error in  this line [amountText2.setText(Float.parseFloat(amountText1.getText().toString()));]

Comment: What is your code? What is your error?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the commas in your `EditText`'s contained string and parse that into a float. From your code above, it should be something like:

```
amountText1.getText().toString().replace(",", "")
```

Here, you're replacing the commas with an empty string which is pretty much the same as removing them.